# Hey can someone help by loading a node with node_load()

Tags: drupal-7

I check if a specific content exists with

```
// Check If node already exists
   $nodeexist = db_select('field_data_field_id', 'r')
     ->fields ('r', array('field_id_value'))
     ->condition ('field_id_value', $row->id, '=')
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAssoc();
```

If it doesn´t exist I create new content,
but if it exist how can i load it, to change some parameters,
will be thankfull for help

Comment: $row->id = nid  ?

Comment: No It is an company Id in my table. Based on it i decide to create new content or update existing with node_load, but i don´t know how to get the nid, to use node_load($nid);

Comment: field_data_field_id <= it's a field attached to node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If field is attached to Node , you can find nid with 'entity_id' column , like this :

```
$nid = db_select('field_data_field_id', 'r')
     ->fields ('r', array('entity_id'))
     ->condition ('field_id_value', $row->id, '=')
     ->condition ('entity_type', 'node', '=')
     ->execute()
     ->fetchField();
if(!empty($nid)){
  $node = node_load($nid);
}else{
   // TODO: create new node 
}
```